# PDO output parameter error

Tags: pdo, output-parameter

I am using this SP, am getting both the result when using mysql workbench.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP(IN _start INT,IN _end INT,INOUT _count INT)
BEGIN

   SET _count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl);

   SET @qry = CONCAT('select * from tbl limit ', _start, ',', _end);

   PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

But when using with PDO am returning this error

```
$c=0;
$stmt = $this->_dbc->getConnection()->prepare("CALL SP(0,10,:count)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":count",$c,PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,0);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $c;
PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1414 OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine db22.SP is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

But on changing

```
$this->_dbc->getConnection()->prepare("CALL SP(0,10,**:count**)");
```

to

```
$this->_dbc->getConnection()->prepare("CALL SP(0,10,@count)");
```

am not returning any error, but always getting the count as 0.

1. Whats the difference between :count and @count ?
2. How to get exact count via pdo ?

Comment: `:count` is a placeholder in a prepared statement,  to be filled in by whatever library/language you're using to talk to the database. `@count` is a database-side server variable. If `@count` was not previously set by another query, then it'll evaluate to null.

Comment: But i followed the example from php manual prepared statements. they are using only placeholders to retrieve output returned from mysql cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following workaround:

```
$dbh = $this->_dbc->getConnection()
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL SP(0,10,@count)");
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "SELECT @count AS count";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

You can find more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#101993